# Transfer files from multiple directories into a single one

Tags: command-line, files, directory

I have some folders, for example `/Desktop/tat`, `/Desktop/sac` and `/Desktop/ras`, each of which has many files of different formats.

I want to transfer all the data from these folders to a new one, named `/Desktop/var`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Copying and pasting will certainly do it. Are you asking for a script or something? If so that should have been clearly mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this command which uses [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) to move all files from the directories you mention to `/Desktop/var`:

```
mv /Desktop/{tat,sac,ras}/* /Desktop/var
```

Inside the curly brackets you may add all the directories inside `/Desktop` whose files you want to move to `/Desktop/var`, separated only by commas (`,`), no spaces.

The above command supposes that the `/Desktop/var` directory already exists. If it doesn't, create it before running the command, either with your file manager or by running:

```
mkdir /Desktop/var
```

**NOTE:** The way you have written the directories in your question, indicates that they exist inside your root directory (`/`). While this isn't something that you couldn't have done, it's highly unlikely. Chances are that your `Desktop` directory is inside your home directory (`~`). If that's the case, the above two commands should become:

```
mv ~/Desktop/{tat,sac,ras}/* ~/Desktop/var
```

and

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/var
```

**WARNING: If you have any files with the same filename in the different directories, they will get overwritten. An overwrite by the `mv` command is not recoverable!** (thanks @Dan for mentioning this!)

Comment: The * for filename expansion typically misses files starting with dot (depends upon some environment variables), and depending upon the number of files involved, the command line buffer may overflow when you expect them all to fit on one "line".